# Story of Harut and Marut and Planet Venus (Zahra/Zohra)?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

I have heard a hadith mentioning the story of harut and marut and a women zahra/zohra who tempted them but then was turned into the planet venus. I want to know the source of this hadith/narration and whether it's authentic or not?

I believe its reported by Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal through a authentic musral chain from the tabi'een..... Can you please provide the sources and evidence of authenticity?

Comment: https://www.al-islam.org/hayat-al-qulub-vol-1-allamah-muhammad-baqir-al-majlisi/account-harut-and-marut Found it on here, however it does not seem authentic as it speaks of angels having desires and that they disobey God, we know both conditions are false, so to me it seems un-authentic

Answer (score 1):

This hadith is in [musnad Ahmad](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=6&bookhad=6143) and in [as-Sunan al-Kobra of Imam al-Bayhaqi](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=71&bookhad=19058) and you will find it in [tafsir ibn Kathir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=49&surano=2&ayano=102) on verse ([2:102](http://legacy.quran.com/2/102)) who quoted it saying and here I'll quote the hadith on the matter and discussion if his sanad (chain) is sahih (sane) and whether it is marfo' (correctly) and discussion of what was mentioned about it:

> ذكر الحديث الوارد في ذلك إن صح سنده ورفعه وبيان الكلام عليه :

In this discussion he (ibn Kathir) says the narrators of this chain except for Musa ibn Jubayr موسى بن جبير are narrators of the sahih hadiths. But Musa ibn Jubayr is an unkonwn and he's apparently the only one who narrated this hadith from Nafi' from ibn 'Omar. Also note that his student (or the person who narrted from him) Zuhayr ibn Muhammad [زهير بن محمد](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=1316&bk_no=60&flag=1) is not an all over accepted narrator as he is also known for manakeer! So the chain on the whole is weak, and it is a marfo' narration (not mursal!) as according the "narration" ibn 'Omar said that our Prophet () said so!

Al-Bayhaqi and ibn Kathir also mentioned other narrations (two different chains) saying ibn 'Omar has narrated this from [Ka'ab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka%27ab_al-Ahbar) (al-Ahbar) which they both considered as more sahih (authentic), so in this case it isn't a hadith rather than an narration based on knowledge of people of the book as  Ka'ab was a former Jew.